# Populating object before build

Tags: c#, .net, git, deployment, pre-build-event

I have MVC project , but now I want to make version handler containing all the information about git repository , the problem is that when run locally it works perfect using LibGit2Sharp library, but when my application is deployed on the server LibGit2Sharp can't instantiate `Repository object` because there is no git installed on server and the destination where application runs is not git repository also, which leads me to think that I need to populate some object just before deploying the application and afterwards use it to grab the information.

Now I know that this can be done with assembly attribute I think and pre-build task , but I am not so sure how exactly , however my question is not only how but if there is another way to deal with this (maybe better practice?) without needing to install git or make git repositories on the server this is out of question.